# Text to binary database

Tags: c, text, file-io, binary

I need help turning a text file into a binary file for C. I can't proceed with my program even though I've written half of it because I don't know if any values are being printed. The conversion requires a max, width, length, and a string for people or animals. Basically the program I'm writing reads the binary database file and returns all values that satisfy the search. Thanks for the help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
int max;
double length, width;
char people;
} max_t;

int 
main()
{
FILE *database;
int inp, out;

        database = fopen("database.txt", "r");
    fscanf(database, "Max : %d", &max);
    fscanf(database, "Width : %lf", &width);
    fscanf(database, "Length : %lf", &length);
    fscanf(database, "People : %s", &people);
    fwrite(&max, 1, sizeof(max), database);
    fwrite(&width, 1, sizeof(width), database);
    fwrite(&length, 1, sizeof(length), database);
    fwrite(&people, 1, sizeof(people), database);
        database = fopen("out.txt", "wb");

return(0);
}
```

Comment: Welcome, and please learn first how to ask a proper question so that you will get useful responses.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask  You don't show any code, or anything of value that can assist someone in helping you.

Comment: Thank You for the welcome. I don't have a code for the conversion because my book is so vague. I've been searching high and low within stackoverflow and other websites and nothing of use has shown up. It seems like it's just a simple i/o that takes text and returns binary with those subfields but I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Show what you have and take it from there.

Comment: Added, based on books example but modified to my needs. Thanks

Comment: You've written that you want to use a binary database, yet the code you show uses `.txt` endings for both files which does not make the code fail but is likely to confuse users. Aside from that next step read some data from the input file and write it in a different format to a output file. Then do that in a loop.

Comment: Have you defined a structure for your database?

Comment: Yes I just created the structure, I have no idea why it's a under txt but I was told I needed to create it in a text format then convert it. Makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Hamas4: use `database = fopen("database.txt","r")`, you are using int to denote FILE*, which is throwing the warning

Comment: Fixed, thanks! I'm not sure if I should keep the out file extension to .txt or change it to .bin but it's showing a 0kb file so I'm not 100% sure anything is writing in there. Which opening the out.txt file shows nothing

Comment: @Hamas4: you are writing in database only!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making some silly mistakes. You are not writing anything in the output file, yet writing into the input file, opened in "read-only" mode!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct s{
int max;
double length, width;
char people[10];
} max_t;

int main()
{
    FILE *database, *out;
    //int inp, out;
    max_t inp;
    database = fopen("database.txt", "r");
    out = fopen("out.txt", "wb");
    fscanf(database, "Max : %d", &inp.max);
    fscanf(database, "Width : %lf", &inp.width);
    fscanf(database, "Length : %lf", &inp.length);
    fscanf(database, "People : %s", inp.people);
    fwrite(&inp.max, 1, sizeof(inp.max), out);
    fwrite(&inp.width, 1, sizeof(inp.width), out);
    fwrite(&inp.length, 1, sizeof(inp.length), out);
    fwrite(inp.people, 1, sizeof(inp.people), out);    
    fclose(database);
    fclose(out);
    return(0);
}
```

EDIT: see main() & structure

Comment: I thought it was doing r/w :/ my bad. I made the changes you suggested above but I'm getting errors telling me that warning: passing arg 4 of `fwrite' makes pointer from integer without a cast but I'm working on fixing that at the moment. Thanks

Comment: @Hamas4: I edited my main(). I forgot to use the structure :)

Comment: Thanks! This is going to sound stupid but any reason why my structure is not being found in the main? It keeps telling me that max, width, length, people are undeclared.

Comment: @Hamas4: See the new structure definition. I added the array limit for people, and changed the typedef declaration. The structure is not being found in main because our typedef was not proper:)

Comment: I think i figured it out, but not sure if it's correct. changed all the lines to fwrite(&inp.max, 1, sizeof(inp.max), out); and errors went away. As in inp.max/width/length/people.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is place data into a file in binary format, and then read it in later you can dump raw bytes into a file with `fwrite` in `stdio.h`.

To read in that data you can use `fread`.

When you use `frwite` to place bytes into a file, you just have to remember what bytes represent what when you read them back in later.

Example txt file:

```
width  : 2
height : 3

3 1
2 3
2 1
```

You can use a couple fscanf calls to read in the 2 and 3:

```
// fp -- FILE * -- file pointer
fscanf( fp, "width  : %d", &width );
fscanf( fp, "height : %d", &height );
```

Then to write these values in binary format you can do:

```
frwite( &width,  1, sizeof( width  ), fp );
frwite( &height, 1, sizeof( height ), fp );
```

Reading in the rest of the file and transferring it into binary format to another file would be the same process.

Comment: I know I can use fwrite because I used it in the main program, but do I use fwrite in the file I want to convert to binary?

Comment: You just call `frwrite` and give it the data you want to place into the file. It will write this data in binary format into the file. You can use `fscanf` to read in data in text format. I'll edit my post and provide a short example.

Comment: What does the FP mean? I haven't seen that notation in my book

Comment: Thanks I got it. I updated the code above but I'm getting an error: binary.c:19: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
binary.c:28: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
binary.c:30:2: warning: no newline at end of file.